# Agent time-in-state statistics

Tags: anylogic

I'm interested to know the different methods the AnyLogic community uses to record time in state statistics.  To explain what I mean, I'll give you an example:

Say I am modelling a movie theatre with multiple cinemas.  Each cinema is modelled as an agent with a state chart in which the cinema can be in one of a number of states:

- Idle (cinema is not currently being used)
- Filling (cinema is open and is filling with patrons)
- InSession (a movie is currently playing)
- Emptying (patrons is open after the movie and patrons are leaving)
- Soiled (cinema is empty after a movie session but is yet to have been cleaned)
- Cleaning (cleaners are doing their thing)

Suppose I now want to record and output statistics on the time and count of states that each cinema is in along the lines of:

Cinema 1 States:

```
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| State     | Occurrences | Average Time | % Total Time |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| Idle      | 25          | 60           | 20%          |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| Filling   | 50          | 20           | 10%          |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| InSession | 50          | 90           | 40%          |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| Etc.      | ...         | ...          | ...          |
+-----------+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Please share the techniques that you use to achieve this in AnyLogic.

Answer (score 2):

No matter what you do, you need to create a variable that collects the info...

**Occurrences:**
You have a variable called occurrences starts with 0 and increments 1 each time the agent enters the state. You can calculate the average for all the agents later doing `average(cinemas,c->c.occurrences)`

**AverageTime:**
you can use either a collection from the agents palette or data set or statistics from the analysis.. there are so many ways to do this that I won't list them here, but data sets a stastics objects have their own average (getYmean and mean respectively) functions that you can use. 
In the case of the state idle, You would have to have a variable timeIdle for instance that you increment every time unit whenever the state is idle

```
if(inState==idle) timeIdle+=timeUnit
```

And when the agent exits the state, or at the end of the simulation, or when you want to measure the value you can do data.add(timeIdle) if you are using a data set, and when you need to retrieve the average time you can do data.getYmean() if it's a data set object, or data.mean() if it's a statistics object

**%total time:**
same thing having a variable called percTotalTime... doing `percTotalTime=timeIdle/time()` whenever you need to read the value.

*You would have to do the same thing for each state.*