# Measuring and displaying agent duration in states

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I would like to build on to the query from the following link: [Agent time-in-state statistics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49595827/agent-time-in-state-statistics)

In my scenario, I have a varying number of agents and I need to display the duration spent in each state by all the agents within the resource pool on a bar chart. In short, each bar in the bar chart must display the total time spent in a specific state for all the agents.

Is there any way to let the bar chart data be a value that loops through the agents within the resource pool and sum up their total duration in each state which is periodically refreshed? Thanks!

Comment: Sure, make the bar chart pull data from a function. Make the function loop across all your agents and sum the time in state (as is done in that query you link). But this is probably not too helpful. However, your question is simply too broad. "Can it be done" questions are almost always not specific enough. See https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow how to improve your question and get the answer you *really* look for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your referenced answer you need to record the time spent in each state using a variable, and then display this variable in the barchart.

See example below

[image]

I have a an agent with a simple statechart and for each state I record the time you enter the state to a variable in the agent. Then when you exit I save the duration (difference between the enter time and the current time) to a variable on main.

On main there is a population of these agents, all of them saving the time they spent in each state to the variables on main.

Then also on main I have a bar chart that simply displays the variables

[image]

And here is result when you run it

[image]

Comment: NB: This way of implementing it is clear for beginners (and so a good answer to the question, so +1), but it would be better to make it generic by structuring the time-in-state data (as a map of statechart state to time-in-state) and dynamically add bars to the chart for each such state. (That way you can also reuse the code for any statechart, and it avoids having to have a bunch of manually-created variables for each state.) But that requires some Java knowledge (and potentially some knowledge of how AnyLogic represents statecharts internally to make the code as 'efficient' as possible)...

Comment: Yes, definitely! Thank you for adding the comment @StuartRossiter (and the +1). I would never implement it like this myself in a normal project. That said we have a library object that we use. You only call `enterState(String stateName)` and likewise for exit state. It simply uses string so we can use it for anything not just statecharts. It has multiple features for providing outputs and checking state changes.